# getdate() returns wrong time

Tags: php

Server hour using "date" via shell (linux server) returns 17:00 , `time()` in a php file returns 17:00 , `getdate()` in the same php file returns 11:00.

I tried `date_default_timezone_set('')` with different timezones but `getdate()` returns the current real hour minus 6 hours.

Someone have any idea on why this happens and/or how can i fix this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try `date_timezone_set('some timezone')` instead where 'some timezone' should be your desired zone.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');` 
line before `$today = getdate();`

Answer (score 0):

[getDate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php)

"Returns an associative array containing the date information of the timestamp, or the current local time if no timestamp is given."

You could use something like this.

```
 $date = date("Date-For-mat", time());
```

splitting the $date value by the format delimiter if you need it in array form.