# PHP getdate not returning the correct time?

Tags: php

I have my timezone set as Africa/Johannesburg (+2GMT) in php.ini. `getdate` says the hour is 0. The hour is actually 3 and if it somehow still stayed in UTC, it would say 11 AM. I changed my pc time and it's still not working. What else could cause this?

Comment: Did you restart apache after you changed the php.ini?

Comment: See [getdate() returns wrong time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365083/getdate-returns-wrong-time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
```